# LIKE operator in R (on Databricks)

Tags: r, azure, databricks

Here is a simple update, which works perfectly:

*reg$region <- ifelse( reg$region %in% ('xxx'), 'yyy' , reg$region)*

How do I change this so it updates the region column when it CONTAINS given string? The above works for the exact match.

In SQL it would be like this:

*UPDATE reg
SET region = case when region like '%xxx%' then 'yyy' else region end;*

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: if you're working with Spark dataframe, then you need the `when` function.  Unfortunately I'm not R expert, and can't give you an example

Comment: In other languages there is like or rlike functions, not sure about R

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Alex, this really helped - managed to find the solution. The WHEN function can use CONTAINS function which I thought was impossible to be used with IFELSE.
Then I realized it can be used in a different way - without those %...% operators.

So it works now when used as below:

***reg$region <- ifelse( contains( reg$region, 'xxx'), 'yyy' , reg$region)***